# Why can't I access class library methods/properties when referenced as a DLL?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll

I've created a class library and built a dll (release build). I've then referenced the DLL in another project (I've tried several). I can see the namespace and classes in Object Browser and I can declare instances of the classes but I cannot use or see any of the methods or properties! there is no IntelliSense whatsoever and calling the methods manualy results in a 'Declaration expected' error.

Within the class library solution I have a unit test project referencing the class library project which works all works fine (and all the tests pass).

Can anyone provide any pointers to what might be going wrong here? I've built plenty of dlls in the past and have had no trouble referencing them at all.

**EDIT: Sample class (as you can see it's very simple)

```
Public Class NTSCurrency
    Implements IComparable

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal code As String, ByVal name As String)
        _Code = code
        _Name = name
    End Sub

    Private _Code As String
    Private _Name As String

    Public Property Code() As String
        Get
            Return _Code
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Code = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Me.Name
    End Function

    Public Function CompareTo(ByVal obj As Object) As Integer Implements System.IComparable.CompareTo
        Dim cur As NTSCurrency = CType(obj, NTSCurrency)
        Return Name.CompareTo(cur.Name)
    End Function

End Class
```

** UPDATE: Just tested this dll with an existing solution and it works fine. Is there a setting somewhere for new projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody laugh...

This was because I was trying to reference the dll methods and properties outside a sub or method definition.

2 hours of my life wasted.

Thanks to all who helped.

Comment: Ha ha ha! Oh, sorry - I couldn't help it... Don't worry, I think we've all been there. Even Raymond Chen does things like that. http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22old+new+thing%22+%22not+my+finest+hour%22+site%3Amsdn.com

Answer (score 3):

Check what scope you have given to your class, methods and properties.  Are they public, or if they are protected are you inheriting from the class?  If the class is abstract then you will not be able to instantiate an instance of it.

Andrew

Comment: I would also suspect that there are no public members in those classes.

Comment: All classes/properties/methods etc are properties. There is no inheritance (or MustInherit, Protected etc). Baffling...

Answer (score 0):

So you have assembly A which you can call from assembly B (unit tests) but not from assembly C (production code)? Sounds bizarre to me. Have I misunderstood you?

You could try gradually changing assembly B code into assembly C one tiny step at a time and see where it stops working.